# NetSuite ODBC Limitations

Tags: sql, oracle, function, odbc, netsuite

I'm trying to find out if anyone is aware of any list of the limitations of NetSuite's ODBC SuiteAnalytics Connect Service being used through OpenQuery? I've been running into many problems with some of my more complex queries failing for no apparent reason, and I finally started narrowing it down to some sort of strange limitations that I wasn't expecting from an Oracle ODBC. Here's a few examples that I've found so far:

- Can't use a basic CTE

Basic Oracle Query:

[image: Basic Oracle Query]

Basic Query as CTE in SQL Server:

[image: Basic Query as CTE in SQL Server]

Basic Query as CTE in Oracle NetSuite via OpenQuery (note the unhelpful response saying basically ("don't work"):

[image: Basic Query as CTE in Oracle NetSuite via OpenQuery]

- Can't use the TRUNC(date) function

Selecting SYSDATE:

[image: Selecting SYSDATE]

Selecting and truncating SYSDATE (note the error, even though [according to Oracle, the format parameter is OPTIONAL:](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm)

[image: Selecting and truncating SYSDATE]

Selecting and truncating SYSDATE using both apparently required parameters (using a valid "format" mask from Oracle's page). Note the unhelpful error of "TRUNC returned error":

[image: Selecting and truncating SYSDATE using both apparently required parameters]

- Can't use LISTAGG() function

Basic query for items' full names:

[image: Basic query for items' full names]

Same query while attempting to use [Oracle's correct format for LISTAGG](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030), note again the unhelpful "Syntax error in SQL statement":

[image: Same query while attempting to use Oracle's correct format for LISTAGG]

- Subqueries that work fine on their own seem to fail when inserted inside of a larger query for some reason (examples to come Soon™)

I'm trying to understand these limitations and learn what they are, but it's like poking at a black box!

Comment: Why?  What errors are you getting?  A bland 'cant use' doesnt give us much to go on.

Comment: @alexherm that's EXACTLY my frustrations. 90% of the time when I do get a response back, that's essentially what I get, a generic unhelpful error that means nothing. When I get back into work on Monday I'll update my question with some examples.

Comment: @alexherm I've updated the question with a few basic examples, if that helps anything. I'm just very frustrated after coming from an environment where I had direct database access to an Oracle database, finding that I cannot accomplish some of the same basic things while trying to use OpenQuery to access our NetSuite database, which presumably is based on Oracle technology.

Comment: Unless things have changed you need to supply a FROM when using Oracle. Usually accomplished by adding `FROM DUAL`.

Comment: @Brian things must have changed, because the successful statements obviously processed without errors. It was only after adding the modifiers that it failed. In fact, when I try to use DUAL, it tells me that DUAL is not a valid object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a followup to this for anyone that comes after me...

I have contacted NetSuite directly, since I could find an answer nowhere else, and they informed me that they only support methods and objects that existed in SQL-92.

Here is their response:

> According to our Project Manager,users are not connecting to an Oracle Database >directly. SuiteAnalytics Connect uses its own (virtual) schema that can be queried >in a way that is compliant with SQL-92.

> Some Oracle-specific functions work, too, but is not guaranteed to work properly. >Users are discouraged from using queries that depend on version of Oracle DB.

So, while it's very frustrating, it looks like anyone that wants to do anything fancy with NetSuite's SQL implementation can't use anything that's not already existent in SQL-92 or lower. CTEs and ListAgg() therefore, are out.