# Repeating value for all dates that fall between two columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking to get the daily rate of individuals given a time range in two columns.

| Start Date | End Date | Daily Rate | Entity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07/23 | 08/06 | 212 | A |
| 07/23 | 08/06 | 175 | B |
| 07/23 | 08/06 | 202 | C |
| 07/23 | 08/06 | 301 | D |
| 07/23 | 08/06 | 215 | E |

For all dates in this range I want a row that will repeat each entity's daily rate. Like below but this trend will continue on entity A until it hits 08/06 and then move onto entity B.

| Start Date | End Date | Daily Rate | Entity | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07/23 | 08/06 | 212 | A | 07/23 |
| 07/23 | 08/06 | 212 | A | 07/24 |
| 07/23 | 08/06 | 212 | A | 07/25 |
| 07/23 | 08/06 | 212 | A | 07/26 |
| 07/23 | 08/06 | 212 | A | 07/27 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 07/23 | 08/06 | 212 | A | 08/06 |
| 07/23 | 08/06 | 175 | B | 07/23 |
| 07/23 | 08/06 | 175 | B | 07/24 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I also need this to work for any date range, not just this one date range.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating dates between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16207543/generating-dates-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 2):

You can use recursive subquery factoring:

```
with rcte (start_date, end_date, daily_rate, entity, one_date) as (
  select start_date, end_date, daily_rate, entity, start_date
  from your_table
  union all
  select start_date, end_date, daily_rate, entity, one_date + 1
  from rcte
  where one_date < end_date
)
select start_date, end_date, daily_rate, entity, one_date
from rcte
order by entity, one_date
```

The anchor member gets the original table data plus a starting date value equal to the start date. The recursive member then adds one day to that date, until it reaches the end date.

| START_DATE | END_DATE | DAILY_RATE | ENTITY | ONE_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-23 | 2022-08-06 | 212 | A | 2022-07-23 |
| 2022-07-23 | 2022-08-06 | 212 | A | 2022-07-24 |
| 2022-07-23 | 2022-08-06 | 212 | A | 2022-07-25 |
| 2022-07-23 | 2022-08-06 | 212 | A | 2022-07-26 |
| 2022-07-23 | 2022-08-06 | 212 | A | 2022-07-27 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2022-07-23 | 2022-08-06 | 212 | A | 2022-08-03 |
| 2022-07-23 | 2022-08-06 | 212 | A | 2022-08-04 |
| 2022-07-23 | 2022-08-06 | 212 | A | 2022-08-05 |
| 2022-07-23 | 2022-08-06 | 212 | A | 2022-08-06 |
| 2022-07-23 | 2022-08-06 | 175 | B | 2022-07-23 |
| 2022-07-23 | 2022-08-06 | 175 | B | 2022-07-24 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2022-07-23 | 2022-08-06 | 175 | B | 2022-08-06 |
| 2022-07-23 | 2022-08-06 | 202 | C | 2022-07-23 |
| 2022-07-23 | 2022-08-06 | 202 | C | 2022-07-24 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2022-07-23 | 2022-08-06 | 202 | C | 2022-08-06 |
| 2022-07-23 | 2022-08-06 | 301 | D | 2022-07-23 |
| 2022-07-23 | 2022-08-06 | 301 | D | 2022-07-24 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2022-07-23 | 2022-08-06 | 301 | D | 2022-08-06 |
| 2022-07-23 | 2022-08-06 | 215 | E | 2022-07-23 |
| 2022-07-23 | 2022-08-06 | 215 | E | 2022-07-24 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2022-07-23 | 2022-08-06 | 215 | E | 2022-08-06 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=953ce38ba8af1cf635ddb797bfd7312b)

You could also use a hierarchical query, but that gets a bit messy (or at least unintuitive) when dealing with multiple source rows as you have to introduce an indeterminate function call to make it work.

Comment: I think this is on the right track unfortunately I cant use cte. I am wondering if you you would be able to help with the hierarchical query or another method

Comment: The answer by SadlyFullStack shows a hierarchical query. But why cat'y you use a CTE? (Recursive wasn't available before 11gR2 I think, but that's pretty old...)

Comment: I believe it is this same issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62223226/netsuite-odbc-limitations

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 12, you can `CROSS APPLY` a hierarchical query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   your_table t
       CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT start_date + LEVEL - 1 AS one_date
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY
                start_date + LEVEL - 1 <= end_date
       )
```

or `CROSS JOIN LATERAL`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   your_table t
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT start_date + LEVEL - 1 AS one_date
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY
                start_date + LEVEL - 1 <= end_date
       )
```

Or, on earlier versions, you can `JOIN` to a hierarchical query that generates sufficient rows to cover all the ranges:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       t.start_date + l.day AS one_date
FROM   your_table t
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT LEVEL - 1 AS day
         FROM   (SELECT MAX(end_date - start_date) AS diff FROM your_table)
         CONNECT BY LEVEL - 1 <= diff
       ) l
       ON (l.day <= t.end_date - t.start_date)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=c6b88303da76e0ddd73b865d64e5cebe)*